# How to check for emitted event inside solidity constructor when writing hardhat tests?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, testing, chai

Say I have contract Foo:

```
contract Foo {

event OwnerAdded(address indexed owner);

address public owner;

constructor(address _owner) {
    owner = _owner
    emit OwnerAdded(owner)
}
```

How would I write my hardhat test to check for the OwnerAdded() emit?

I was trying to do:

```
await expect(fooFactory.deploy(testAddr)).to.emit(Foo, "OwnerAdded).withArgs("0x83h342e46571f77h0531d")
```

But obviously, that doesn't work because you need the contract object to pass to the Chai `emit` assertion.

Comment: I know this is now what you're looking for but testing things like this is easy-peasy in [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send the deploy transaction and wait for the receipt, and then check if it emitted the desired event, something like this:

```
const tx = fooFactory.deploy(testAddr);
const receipt = await tx.wait();
const event = receipt.events
        ?.filter(({ event }) => event == "OwnerAdded")
expect(event).to.not.be.null;
expect(event.args.owner).to.be.equals("0x83h342e46571f77h0531d");
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the error: "tx.wait is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it as the previous answer fails with `tx.wait is not a function`:

```
const tx = fooFactory.deploy(testAddr);
const receipt = await tx.deployTransaction.wait();
const event = receipt.events.find(event => event.event === "OwnerAdded");
const [owner] = event.args;
expect(event).to.not.be.null;
expect(owner).to.equal("0x83h342e46571f77h0531d");
```